# FTDI ft232rl 3.3V logic interfacing PIC microcontroller

Tags: pic, ftdi, logic-level

I want to interface a ft232 with PIC16F73. I am using the circuit below:
[image: ft232 interfaing mcu]

VCCIO is connected with VCC which is 5V. Then I think all logics from TXD,RXD will be 5V, isn't it?
If I connect VCCIO with 3V3OUT then what will happen? will RXD,TXD be 3.3V logic?
Is there any problem if I connect VCCIO with 3V3OUT, PIC16F73 is powered from 5V. I am newbie in electronics so forgive me if the problem is too easy.

Comment: Why do you need pic at 5v and rx/tx at 3.3V?

Comment: I am trying to make PCB. But It seems very hard to connect to VCCIO to VCC since there is lot of connections. But it is easy to connect VCCIO with 3V3. So if there is no problem I want to connect VCCIO to 3V3. But i am in confusion whether it will work or not.

Comment: The data sheet doesn't really say but I wouldn't recommend it. You would be driving RXD with 5V when the internal logic is at 3.3V, and this will typically damage the chip. Hard to connect is not a good reason. :) Are you making a single sided board, is that why? If so, use a wire jumper to cross signal lines.

Comment: Looking at the FTDI datasheet, I suspect it will survive. However, unless you need full-time serial access over USB, another option might be to have the FTDI off-board. This saves space and there are plenty of off the shelf adapters that are 3.3 vs 5v switchable.

Answer (score 3):

Answer straight from the Datasheet:

> VCCIO
>   +1.8V to +5.25V supply to the UART Interface and CBUS group  pins (1...3, 5, 6, 
>   9...14, 22, 23). In USB bus powered designs connect this pin to 3V3OUT pin to  drive out at +3.3V levels, or connect to VCC to drive out at
>   5V CMOS level.

So Yes, if you connect VCCIO to the 3V3OUT, RxD, TxD etc. will all be at 3.3V level. Since your microcontroller is using 5V level, you should not do this but connect VCCIO to VCC (which is 5V).

Comment: Actually I want to know that if i connect VCCIO to 3V3 then will PIC16F73 communicate with ft232?

Comment: Ah. Looking at page 123 it seems the minimal voltage for a '1' is 2.0V so I think the micro controller should be ok. However, you need to check the FTDI data sheet is it can withstand 5.0v from the micro controller if it operates at 3.3V.

Comment: Looking at the FTDI datasheet, I suspect it will survive. However, unless you need full-time serial access over USB, another option might be to have the FTDI off-board. This saves space and there are plenty of off the shelf adapters that are 3.3 vs 5v switchable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since i want to make a PCB of my PIC Test board, I want to have a serial communication feature when i need. During design only one connection is left which is VCCIO. I can connect VCCIO to VCC but it seems a huge change is needed in components placements and routes. But connecting VCCIO to 3V3OUT is easy. So I need the specific information that whether it will be any problem.

Comment: The only thing I can say is that I've regularly forgot to change the level on my FTDI breakout and it's still working fine. I think you'll be ok.